# Ml file reading limits

Tags: file, input, smlnj, ml

I want to read from file but, when I use inputAll or inputLine, it read only 70 character from each line.
how can I read from file without limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be seeing this limitation. If you can get a repro, I'd be happy to look into / fix it:
https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/bugform.php